# How to achieve browser resizing in run time using playwright? in a e2e test run

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, ui-automation, playwright, playwright-test

We have in protractor like:
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(
width - 30,
height
);

How to achieve this in playwright?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 

Comment: You can pass a custom viewport in the playwright.config.ts see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions or when creating a new context if you are using the library: https://playwright.dev/docs/emulation#viewport

Comment: Thanks Max, I need to resize window and reset it back to its original between a test and in the same browser context. How can I get current size dynamically and +/- some pixels from it?

Answer (score 21):

To resize your playwrite browser window: you can use the method [`page.setViewportSize()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-set-viewport-size)

For Example:

```
import { test, expect, devices } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  page.setViewportSize({ width: 600, height: 600 });
  // do stuff then resize to a particular device size 
  page.setViewportSize(devices['iPhone X'].viewport);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the equivalent functionality by using `page.viewportSize()` to get the current viewport and re-setting it using `page.setViewportSize()`

**Example:**

```
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test("costume viewport size", async ({ page }) => {
  // Get the current viewport size
  const viewport = page.viewportSize();

  if (viewport) {
    const newWidth = viewport.width - 30;
    const newHeight = viewport.height;

    // Set the new viewport size
    await page.setViewportSize({ width: newWidth, height: newHeight });
  }

  // ...rest of the test
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed alternative method to resize the window, not just the viewport. You can accomplish this with Playwright's `Page.evaluate()` function.

An example of your main process:

```js
function createWindow(): void {
    win = new BrowserWindow({ <yourPropsHere> })
    ...
}

function setWindowSize(width: number, height: number) {
  win?.setSize(width, height);
}

ipcMain.on('set-window-size', (_event: IpcMainEvent, width: number, height: number): void => {
  setWindowSize(width, height);
});
```

An example of your Playwright Electron launch code (see [playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-electron)):

```js
const { _electron: electron } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Launch Electron app.
  const electronApp = await electron.launch({ args: ['main.js'] });

  // Get the first window that the app opens, wait if necessary.
  const window = await electronApp.firstWindow();

  // this is the magic part that resizes the window
  window.evaluate(
    (): void => {
      const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
      return ipcRenderer.send('set-window-size', 2560, 1440);
    });

  // Exit app.
  await electronApp.close();
})();
```